# KSQL: Topic backing a KSQL table not get compacted

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using KSQL to track the delay between stops for a fleet management system, for simplicity I have 2 streams `trips` and `tasks`, they get their data feed from debezium, so far so good.

My problem is when I create a KSQL table that reflects some aggregated data, I assume that the backing topic should eventually have a compacted results, but in fact it is not, as in the below example

```
-- trips stream
CREATE STREAM trips_raw (
            id bigint, gross_merchandise_value double, vehicle_id bigint, trip_code string,
            status string,time_slot string,  number_of_orders integer, supplier_id integer, 
            trip_start_time bigint, agent_id integer, trip_number integer,  returnes_handled BOOLEAN,
            modification_date bigint, created_by integer, modified_by integer, creation_date bigint
            )
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='trips', VALUE_FORMAT='json');

--tasks stream
CREATE STREAM tasks_raw (id bigint, delivery_trip_id bigint, agent_id integer, creation_date bigint, 
                                modification_date bigint, 
                                status string, created_by integer, modified_by integer, request_id bigint) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='tasks',VALUE_FORMAT='json');

-- THE AGGREGATED TABLE (just simple view for sake of simplicity) 
create table trips_actions_count as
    select count(1), ID from trips_raw
    group by ID;


----- TEST DATA ------
 INSERT INTO trips_raw (
    id, gmv, vehicle_id , trip_code, status, trip_start_time , MODIFICATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, MODIFIED_BY,CREATION_DATE
) VALUES (
    1, 100.5, 523, 'TRIP_1', 'CREATED', 1616480285000, 1616530285000, 123, 123, 1616444781000
);

 INSERT INTO trips_raw (
    id, gmv, vehicle_id , trip_code, status, trip_start_time , MODIFICATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, MODIFIED_BY,CREATION_DATE
) VALUES (
    1, 100.5, 523, 'TRIP_1', 'ARRIVED', 1616480285000, 1616540285000, 123, 123, 1616444781000
);

 INSERT INTO trips_raw (
    id, gmv, vehicle_id , trip_code, status, trip_start_time , MODIFICATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, MODIFIED_BY,CREATION_DATE
) VALUES (
    1, 100.5, 523, 'TRIP_1', 'COMPLETED', 1616480285000, 1616550285000, 123, 123, 1616444781000
);
```

When I tail the created topic backing the table `TRIPS_ACTIONS_COUNT`, I got the below results,

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TRIPS_ACTIONS_COUNT --from-beginning
{"KSQL_COL_0":1}
{"KSQL_COL_0":2}
{"KSQL_COL_0":3} 

kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topics-with-overrides --topic TRIPS_ACTIONS_COUNT
Topic: TRIPS_ACTIONS_COUNT  PartitionCount: 3   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=1073741824
```

I assume that the `TRIPS_ACTIONS_COUNT` should be compacted, so that when a consumer read it, it should only get the latest value for a specific key, which is in my case `{"KSQL_COL_0":3}`.

I think I am missing something, not sure what is it yet?

Answer (score 0):

You're only printing the values, whereas compaction happens on topic record keys (you need to add `--property print.key=true`), **and** it only happens on closed segments, where the default segment size is 1G... In other words, 3 records is not enough for compaction to occur, anyway

In general, the issue is that you're consuming a stream (a raw topic), which is the changelog of events that happen within the table. You should instead be selecting from your table with the ksql cli if you truly want to see the grouped data

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, however how shall I make a use of this table in my applications (monitoring, tracking, ...), is it just the CLI?